# VTK marching cubes or contour for surface reconstruction using python

Tags: python, vtk, marching-cubes, isosurface

I am new to VTK python. I have a csv file with 8000 point (X, Y, Z) and corresponding 8000 signed distances (sdf)

I am trying to read the data and apply VTK filter to reconstruct the surface at sdf = 0.0, but I dont see any option to create surface at such a value. I have tried this using skimage.measure and pyvista. Both work very well but somehow VTK doesnt product desired input.

```
import numpy as np
import vtk

pointSource = vtk.vtkProgrammableSource()

def readPoints():
    output = pointSource.GetPolyDataOutput()
    points = vtk.vtkPoints()
    output.SetPoints(points)


    pts = np.loadtxt('sdf.csv',delimiter=',')
    for pi in pts:
        points.InsertNextPoint(pi[0], pi[1], pi[2])

pointSource.SetExecuteMethod(readPoints)


# Construct the surface and create isosurface.
surf = vtk.vtkSurfaceReconstructionFilter()
surf.SetInputConnection(pointSource.GetOutputPort())

cf = vtk.vtkContourFilter()
cf.SetInputConnection(surf.GetOutputPort())
cf.SetValue(0, 0.0)
cf.Update()
print(cf.GetNumberOfContours())

map = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
map.SetInputConnection(cf.GetOutputPort())
map.ScalarVisibilityOff()

surfaceActor = vtk.vtkActor()
surfaceActor.SetMapper(map)
surfaceActor.GetProperty().SetDiffuseColor(1.0000, 0.3882, 0.2784)
surfaceActor.GetProperty().SetSpecularColor(1, 1, 1)
surfaceActor.GetProperty().SetSpecular(.4)
surfaceActor.GetProperty().SetSpecularPower(50)

# Create the RenderWindow, Renderer and both Actors
ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renWin = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renWin.AddRenderer(ren)
iren = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
iren.SetRenderWindow(renWin)

# Add the actors to the renderer, set the background and size
ren.AddActor(surfaceActor)
ren.SetBackground(1, 1, 1)
renWin.SetSize(400, 400)
ren.GetActiveCamera().SetFocalPoint(0, 0, 0)
ren.GetActiveCamera().SetPosition(1, 0, 0)
ren.GetActiveCamera().SetViewUp(0, 0, 1)
ren.ResetCamera()
ren.GetActiveCamera().Azimuth(20)
ren.GetActiveCamera().Elevation(30)
ren.GetActiveCamera().Dolly(1.2)
ren.ResetCameraClippingRange()

iren.Initialize()
renWin.Render()
iren.Start()
```

[Incorrect output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXUHB.png)

The data of 8000 points with sdfs is *here* https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FiAjQc6BR_3LAkaNR3qbEfK4odAm30ji/view?usp=sharing

Also Contour or marching cube feature is very slow compared to skimage and pyvista. Is there anything wrong with my code?

Expected output is a Surface, representing a rectangular box around the red colored points [point data and sdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZXV8.png)

Also I am expecting vtk.marchingCube to be very fast. But it takes lot of time to get output for large point cloud

Comment: The bottleneck in your code is coming from the for loop with `points.InsertNextPoint`. VTK has a `numpy_support` module to assist with these sorts of operations so that you can avoid for loops. As for why the contouring is wrong, I suspect its because you are not setting the correct active input array to perform the contouring on. Honestly, you should just use PyVista here as PyVista is a direct wrapping of VTK in Python and will make all of this literally 4 lines of code. (Disclaimer: I helped create PyVista)

Comment: But, if you're committed to VTK and ready to embrace its steep learning curve, you may find the VTK discourse to be a more active support community: https://discourse.vtk.org/